# Misscompare Error in R : Error in mdpat_count[index, ] : incorrect number of dimensions

Tags: r, missing-data, imputation

I am trying to use the `misscompare` library in R, where I am trying to check the randomness of missing values and impute them using that library. I am using a book store data set, which I cant really upload here, as the data size is big. Below is my sample code for reference.

```
check2$User.ID<-as.numeric(check2$User.ID)
check2$ISBN<-as.numeric(check2$ISBN)
cleaned <- missCompare::clean(check2,var_removal_threshold = 1,matrixplot_sort = FALSE)
metadata <- missCompare::get_data(cleaned)
```

When I use `misscompare::getdata`, I get the following error:

```
Error in mdpat_count[index, ] : incorrect number of dimensions
```

Can someone please let me know how did you get rid of this error if you had the luck of working with this library?

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example ?

Answer (score 0):

You could change the input to the `get_data` function.

The `get_data` function does the following:

> get_data extracts descriptive metadata from the dataframe including information on missing data

As it anyway seems to only describe the missing data, you could also try to use your initial data.frame as input. As also mentioned by the `get_data` function description for input parameter `X`.

> X - Original dataframe with samples in rows and variables as columns. Can also use the resulting object from the clean function

Something like:

```
missCompare::get_data(check2)
```

Not quite sure if it works (since you didn't really provide a reproducible example) but probably something I would try.